# appcfg.py: error: Error parsing

Tags: google-app-engine

When I try to deploy my app using google app engine, I get this response always

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\Users\expensivestephen\Desktop\mytinywebdb\app.yaml: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\expensivestephen\Desktop\mytinywebdb\app.yaml", line 1, column 21.
```

And my app.yaml file goes thus;

```
application: meyapay: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
application: meyapay
version: 1 
runtime: python 
api_version: 1

handlers: 
- url: /images 
  static_dir: images

- url: .* 
  script: main.py
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It just worked for me. I still have a little issue though and would love some more help. When I navigate to meyapay.appspot.com I get this error: "Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds."

Comment: You need to check the logs in the developer console.  It probably has something to do with stale code.  You should set your runtime to `python27`, and use `script: main.app`

Comment: what I have in the console is this: (INFO     2014-06-20 19:23:34,904 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2014-06-20 19:10:28,390 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\expensivestephen\Desktop\appinventordb\main.py", line 18, in <module>

    from django.utils import simplejson as json

ImportError: No module named django.utils



INFO     2014-06-20 20:10:28,427 module.py:639] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -) Also I would love if you could guide me through setting the run time to python27 and using script: main.app

Comment: This should be a separate question.  If you are running django, you need to add it under `libraries` in `app.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

I get this error all the time. In my case, it's usually because I copy-pasted the code, and either the punctuation or the spacing is misinterpreted somewhere along the line.

The solution is to type out exactly the same information yourself.